# Web scraping from a list and dictionary

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to web scrape a website using python. I want to scrape data from a  tag and i can't figure out how. There are two lists in there and then there seems to be a dictionary

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/smartphones/nokia/?spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.card.2.323e5fc3B8mWd8&from'
                    '=onesearch_category_3')
# print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
# print(soup)
if "priceCurrency":
    phone = soup.find_all(type="application/ld+json")

print(phone[1])
```

This is my code and this gives me the  tag. I just want to scrape specific elements from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data of the phones on a certain page is located in a json file. I think this is faster than using beautifulsoup, but I am not sure. There is a lot more information than just the name and price, but that is what I put into a dataframe for you to see. View the url in the code to look at all the information.

## Code

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

list_phones = pd.DataFrame()
for page_num in range(1, 5): #Number of pages to search through
    json_page = requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/smartphones/nokia/?ajax=true&page=' + str(page_num)).json()

    for phone in json_page['mods']['listItems']:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[phone['name'], phone['price']]], columns=['Name','Price'])
        list_phones = list_phones.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

print(list_phones)
```

## Output

```
                                                  Name     Price
0          150 - Dual Sim - Camera - Card Slot - White   5050.00
1                   Nokia 105 (2019 )- Dual sim - 1.77   3000.00
2    Nokia 210 - 2.4" - 16MB RAM- Dual SIM -Camera ...   5424.00
3          150 - Dual Sim - Camera - Card Slot - White   4999.00
4    New Nokia 106 2018 Dual Sim High Quality Keypa...   3140.00
5                                       105 Nokia 2019   2999.00
6    Nokia 3310 Mobile Phone - 2.4" QVGA Display - ...   9999.00
7    Nokia  105 2019 1.7 Inch Display 2000 Contact ...   2990.00
8                3310 - Dual Sim - 2.4 Inch LCD - Grey   8200.00
9         130 - 2017 - Dual Sim - Camera - Memory Card   3999.00
10   Nokia 6.1 Plus 4Gb 64Gb Black original (advanc...     26600
11                N 1 1Gb-8Gb - 4.5 Inches - Dark Blue   9500.00
12                      Nokia mobile 105 100% original   1899.00
13         150 - Dual Sim - Camera - Card Slot - Black   4999.00
14                                      nokia 130 2017   3895.00
15                                           Nokia 150   5099.00
16      Nokia 106 - 2018 - 1.8" - Dual Sim - Dark Grey   3098.00
17                       105 - 2017 - Dual Sim - Black   3250.00
18                                           Nokia 210   5450.00
19                 Nokia 105 - Dual sim - 1.77” - 2019   3149.00
20               105 - Dual sim - 1.77” - 2019 - Black   3049.00
21                        105 - 2017 - Dual Sim - Blue   3250.00
22   Nokia 106 (2018) - 1.8" inch Display - 4MB Sto...   3150.00
23                        Nokai 6.1 plus BLUE 4GB 64GB     26600
24          Nokia 3.2 BLACK 3GB 64GB (ADVANCE TELECOM)  25400.00
25                            Nokia 2.2 BLACK 3GB 32GB     17300
26   6.1 2018 - 5.5" - 3Gb Ram - 32G Rom - 16Mp Cam...  24999.00
27    3.1 Plus - 6 inches Display - 3Gb Ram - 32Gb Rom  19900.00
28                Nokia 106 2018 - 1.8 inch - Dual Sim   3150.00
29          Nokia 1 Mobile Phone-Dual Sim-1Gb-8Gb-Blue   9500.00
..                                                 ...       ...
130  Nokia 6.1 Plus 4Gb 64Gb Black original (advanc...     26600
131               N 1 1Gb-8Gb - 4.5 Inches - Dark Blue   9500.00
132                     Nokia mobile 105 100% original   1899.00
133        150 - Dual Sim - Camera - Card Slot - Black   4999.00
134                                     nokia 130 2017   3895.00
135                                          Nokia 150   5099.00
136     Nokia 106 - 2018 - 1.8" - Dual Sim - Dark Grey   3098.00
137                      105 - 2017 - Dual Sim - Black   3250.00
138                                          Nokia 210   5450.00
139                Nokia 105 - Dual sim - 1.77” - 2019   3149.00
140              105 - Dual sim - 1.77” - 2019 - Black   3049.00
141                       105 - 2017 - Dual Sim - Blue   3250.00
142  Nokia 106 (2018) - 1.8" inch Display - 4MB Sto...   3150.00
143                       Nokai 6.1 plus BLUE 4GB 64GB     26600
144         Nokia 3.2 BLACK 3GB 64GB (ADVANCE TELECOM)  25400.00
145                           Nokia 2.2 BLACK 3GB 32GB     17300
146  6.1 2018 - 5.5" - 3Gb Ram - 32G Rom - 16Mp Cam...  24999.00
147   3.1 Plus - 6 inches Display - 3Gb Ram - 32Gb Rom  19900.00
148               Nokia 106 2018 - 1.8 inch - Dual Sim   3150.00
149         Nokia 1 Mobile Phone-Dual Sim-1Gb-8Gb-Blue   9500.00
150   150 -2.4"- Dual Sim - Camera - Card Slot - black   5050.00
151  Nokia 3.1 Plus - 6’’ HD+ display-Camera Front ...  18999.00
152           Nokia 210 Mobile Phone - 2.4" - 16MB RAM   5449.00
153                                       Nokia 7 Plus  33999.00
154  nokia 106 2018 /Nokia 106, 2000 contacts phone...   3000.00
155  N 8110 Dual Sim - 2.45" Lcd - 2.5Gb Rom - 2Mp ...  10000.00
156  nokia 210 2.4 inch 16 mb ram internet black   ...   5425.00
157                          Nokia 1 plus Mobile Phone  12499.00
158                                    3310 - Dual Sim   8000.00
159                                 Nokia 7.1 4GB/64GB  31699.00

[160 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thnx bro...This is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :contains to target the required script tag (otherwise use `soup.find_all(type="application/ld+json")[1]` ), or loop each `script` tag and then check `if "priceCurrency" in script.text:`. Your current set-up will always return `True`.

When you extract the .text from the tag you have json you can parse with json library. The initial return is a dictionary. The key 'itemListElement' returns a collection of offers (dictionaries). You can loop that list and access items from each inner dictionary by key. `'offers'` returns a dictionary however so you would need to again access items from that by key.

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/smartphones/nokia/?spm=a2a0e.searchlistcategory.card.2.323e5fc3B8mWd8&from=onesearch_category_3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
phones = soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]:contains(priceCurrency)')
data = json.loads(phones.text)

for offer in data['itemListElement']:
    print('item name : ' + offer['name'])
    print('item price : ' + offer['offers']['priceCurrency'] + str(offer['offers']['price'])) #etc
```

Comment: Thank you. very much... I had been trying it for 3 days.

Comment: I want to scrap multiple pages from this website. I used a for loop to change the page number in the URL but its giving me same data every time (data from the first page). Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Hi, you should open a new question. I answered the question as posed.